# How can I fill the common http header once in swag-go?

Tags: go, swagger

Each method of my REST api accepts an `Authorization` header. Now I need to fill out the header for each API method in Swagger UI.
How can I write Swagger annotation so I can fill the `Authorization` header once and then all my API methods can use it?

Thanks.